# Impossible for me to open Dropbox in Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, permission, dropbox

I'm working with 2 different Mac systems: 10.1 and 10.6.8. I've installed Dropbox since 1 year. When I was working with Mac number one, the Dropbox of my computer number 2 was updated. But this morning, it's suddenly impossible to open Dropbox on the Snow Leopard Mac. I have nothing changed…

This is the error window:

[image]

When I click on the blue link I get the following:

```
bn.BUILD_KEY: Dropbox
bn.VERSION: 16.4.29
bn.DROPBOXEXT_VERSION: failed
bn.is_frozen: True
pid: 833
ppid: 98
uid: 501
user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='blandinejet', pw_passwd='********', pw_uid=501, pw_gid=20, pw_gecos='Blandine JET', pw_dir='/Users/blandinejet', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
effective_user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='blandinejet', pw_passwd='********', pw_uid=501, pw_gid=20, pw_gecos='Blandine JET', pw_dir='/Users/blandinejet', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
euid: 501
gid: 20
egid: 20
group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='staff', gr_passwd='*', gr_gid=20, gr_mem=['root'])
effective_group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='staff', gr_passwd='*', gr_gid=20, gr_mem=['root'])
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: None
cwd: u'/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources'
     real_path=u'/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources'
            mode=040755 uid=501 gid=20
     parent mode=040755 uid=501 gid=20
HOME: u'/Users/blandinejet'
appdata: u'/Users/blandinejet/.dropbox/instance1'
         real_path=u'/Users/blandinejet/.dropbox/instance1'
                mode=040700 uid=501 gid=20
         parent mode=040700 uid=501 gid=20
dropbox_path: u'/Users/blandinejet/Dropbox'
              real_path=u'/Users/blandinejet/Dropbox'
                        not found
              parent    mode=040755 uid=501 gid=20
sys_executable: '/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/python'
                real_path='/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/python'
                        mode=0100755    uid=501 gid=20
                parent  mode=040755 uid=501 gid=20
trace.__file__: '/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyo'
                real_path='/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyo'
                        not found
                parent  not found
tempdir: u'/var/folders/rb/rb1PniUpG4Wxd06qp+-BGE+++TI/-Tmp-'
         real_path=u'/private/var/folders/rb/rb1PniUpG4Wxd06qp+-BGE+++TI/-Tmp-'
                mode=040700 uid=501 gid=20
         parent mode=040755 uid=501 gid=20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyo", line 5536, in main_startup
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyo", line 2261, in run
  File "ui/common/uikit.pyo", line 539, in create_ui_kit
  File "ui/cocoa/uikit.pyo", line 41, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/ui/cocoa/tray_popup/tray_controller.pyo", line 48, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/ui/cocoa/tray_popup/tray_popup.pyo", line 115, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/ui/server_views/v2/cocoa/__init__.pyo", line 8, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/ui/server_views/v2/cocoa/embeddable.pyo", line 57, in <module>
  File "dropbox/client/ui/server_views/v2/cocoa/webview.pyo", line 22, in <module>
  File "Tungsten/__init__.pyo", line 29, in <module>
  File "objc/_lazyimport.pyo", line 76, in __init__
  File "objc/_lazyimport.pyo", line 38, in _loadBundle
ImportError: Bundle could not be loaded
```

So I tried to reinstall the application following the advises on your website:

1. Stop Dropbox (If needed):
   Click the Dropbox icon in the menu bar at the top of your screen
   Click on the gear icon in the Notifications panel and select 'Quit Dropbox'
2. Download the newest version: www.dropbox.com/install
3. Open your Terminal app (Located at /Applications/Utilities/Terminal)
   Copy and paste the following lines into the Terminal, ONE AT A TIME, and press ENTER
   after each one. PLEASE make sure you copy and paste these commands (don't type them by hand), as getting them wrong could cause some harm. You'll be prompted for your computer's admin password (not your Dropbox password) after entering the first command. Keep in mind that the password field in the terminal will remain blank as you type your password. After you type it, just press ENTER.
4. `sudo chown "$USER" "$HOME"`
   `sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/Dropbox`
   `sudo chmod -R u+rw ~/Dropbox`
   `sudo mv ~/.dropbox ~/.Trash/dropbox.old`
   `sudo mv ~/.dropbox-master ~/.Trash/dropbox-master.old`
   `sudo chmod -N ~`
   `sudo mv /Library/DropboxHelperTools ~/DropboxHelperTools.old`
5. Open the .dmg file from step # 2 and double click the Dropbox icon to install Dropbox.
6. Restart Dropbox from the Applications folder.

**But** it doesn't change anything: it's impossible for me to open the application.
Anyone (a genius) has an idea to help me?

Comment: Those commands seem to have nothing to do with the errors /Users/blandinejet/Dropbox not found and /Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyo'
                        not found - DO these two exist?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't completely uninstalled Dropbox. There are also files under /private/var/dropbox* . Also, remove all Dropbox related files including preferences. The easiest way to find out about that is by using applications like Appcleaner or Easyfind.